# If a page's pte is marked with _PAGE_USER bit to 0, does it result in page fault or general_protection exception?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, mmu

I am trying to understand the protection provided by intel x86 MMU architecture. 
I am confused basically as to when will the MMU raise the page fault(page_fault, int 14) and when will the CPU raise an exception (general_protection fault, int 13). I know that CPU usually raises an exception when there is a mismatch of privilege levels.

But who maps the user/supervisor mode bit to the privilege level, is it the MMU or the CPU?

Particularly, I am not able to interpret who would raise an exception when I clear the _PAGE_USER flag of the pte entry of a page, I expect a fault to be raised by the MMU (or is it the processor?)

Please point me to the resources if you can so that I can read up in case this is available somewhere. Thanks !

Comment: Ok, i think i need to explain the context a bit more. I am trying to track the pages of a process. For this i am relying on this page fault mechanism. I protect the pages and when fault happens, remove protection after accounting. This is not a hw or something. This is something i am trying to do to achieve something else which i have to do on x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But who maps the user/supervisor mode bit to the privilege level, is it the MMU or the CPU?

From (https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/319433-014.pdf)

> Every access to a linear address is either a supervisor-mode
>   access or a user-mode access. All accesses performed while the
>   current privilege level (CPL) is less than 3 are supervisor-mode
>   accesses. If CPL = 3, accesses are generally user-mode accesses.

To be short, ring 3 is **user**, rings 0-2 are **supervisor**.

> Particularly, I am not able to interpret who would raise an exception when I clear the _PAGE_USER flag of the pte entry of a page, I expect a fault to be raised by the MMU (or is it the processor?)

Fault is raised by the MMU which is a part of the CPU on modern computers. So, that doesn't really matter.

`Linux Kernel Development` by Robert Love and `Understanding the Linux Kernel` by Daniel P. Bovet excellently cover this topic. Former has less details about linux kernel implementation on x86 and generally is easier to understand.

Comment: THanks for your reply. I had a confusion regarding general_protection fault versus page fault, i.e., if PAGE_USER bit is 0, does page fault occur or protection fault occur. But i realized that it indeed causes page fault, by experimenting with some changes in the code.